# Convert the first HTML table row into a heading row for each table using XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have some html content inside my XML. Previously I could just use `<xsl:copy-of select="customFields/customField[@name='mainContent']/html"/>` to pull the content into the correct area. A new requirement is to convert the first `<tr>` inside each table's `<tbody>` into a set of `thead/tr/th`.

I am confused on how to convert, in fact not even shore where to start:

...

```
<customField name="mainContent" type="Html">
    <html>
        <h1>Page Heading</h1>
        <p>Gusto te minim tempor elit quam. Dolore vel accumsan parum option me. Demonstraverunt congue nisl soluta tincidunt seacula. Soluta saepius demonstraverunt praesent claritatem mutationem. Modo te ullamcorper vel augue veniam. Nunc investigationes dolor iriure typi in.</p>
        <p>Gusto te minim tempor elit quam. Dolore vel accumsan parum option me. Demonstraverunt congue nisl soluta tincidunt seacula. Soluta saepius demonstraverunt praesent claritatem mutationem. Modo te ullamcorper vel augue veniam. Nunc investigationes dolor iriure typi in.</p>
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" summary="" border="0">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Heading 1</td>
                    <td>Heading 2</td>
                    <td>Heading 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>sample</td>
                    <td>sample</td>
                    <td>sample</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>sample</td>
                    <td>sample</td>
                    <td>sample</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>sample</td>
                    <td>sample</td>
                    <td>sample</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>sample</td>
                    <td>sample</td>
                    <td>sample</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </html>
</customField>
...
```

into:

```
...
<customField name="mainContent" type="Html">
    <html>
        <h1>Page Heading</h1>
        <p>Gusto te minim tempor elit quam. Dolore vel accumsan parum option me. Demonstraverunt congue nisl soluta tincidunt seacula. Soluta saepius demonstraverunt praesent claritatem mutationem. Modo te ullamcorper vel augue veniam. Nunc investigationes dolor iriure typi in.</p>
        <p>Gusto te minim tempor elit quam. Dolore vel accumsan parum option me. Demonstraverunt congue nisl soluta tincidunt seacula. Soluta saepius demonstraverunt praesent claritatem mutationem. Modo te ullamcorper vel augue veniam. Nunc investigationes dolor iriure typi in.</p>
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" summary="" border="0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Heading 1</th>
                    <th>Heading 2</th>
                    <th>Heading 3</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>sample</td>
                    <td>sample</td>
                    <td>sample</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>sample</td>
                    <td>sample</td>
                    <td>sample</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>sample</td>
                    <td>sample</td>
                    <td>sample</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>sample</td>
                    <td>sample</td>
                    <td>sample</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </html>
</customField>
...
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete and short solution, using the most fundamental and powerful XSLT design pattern -- the overriden identity rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have some html content inside my
>   XML. Previously I could just use
>   `<xsl:copy-of
>   select="customFields/customField[@name='mainContent']/html"/>`
>   to pull the content into the correct
>   area. A new requirement is to convert
>   the first `<tr>` inside each table's
>   `<tbody>` into a set of `thead/tr/th`.

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="tbody/tr[1]">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </tr>
  </thead>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="tbody/tr[1]/td">
  <th><xsl:apply-templates/></th>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<customField name="mainContent" type="Html">
    <html>
        <h1>Page Heading</h1>
        <p>Gusto te minim tempor elit quam. Dolore vel accumsan parum option me. Demonstraverunt congue nisl soluta tincidunt seacula. Soluta saepius demonstraverunt praesent claritatem mutationem. Modo te ullamcorper vel augue veniam. Nunc investigationes dolor iriure typi in.</p>
        <p>Gusto te minim tempor elit quam. Dolore vel accumsan parum option me. Demonstraverunt congue nisl soluta tincidunt seacula. Soluta saepius demonstraverunt praesent claritatem mutationem. Modo te ullamcorper vel augue veniam. Nunc investigationes dolor iriure typi in.</p>
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" summary="" border="0">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Heading 1</td>
                    <td>Heading 2</td>
                    <td>Heading 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>sample</td>
                    <td>sample</td>
                    <td>sample</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>sample</td>
                    <td>sample</td>
                    <td>sample</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>sample</td>
                    <td>sample</td>
                    <td>sample</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>sample</td>
                    <td>sample</td>
                    <td>sample</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </html>
</customField>
```

**produces exactly the wanted, correct result**:

```
<customField name="mainContent" type="Html">
   <html>
      <h1>Page Heading</h1>
      <p>Gusto te minim tempor elit quam. Dolore vel accumsan parum option me. Demonstraverunt congue nisl soluta tincidunt seacula. Soluta saepius demonstraverunt praesent claritatem mutationem. Modo te ullamcorper vel augue veniam. Nunc investigationes dolor iriure typi in.</p>
      <p>Gusto te minim tempor elit quam. Dolore vel accumsan parum option me. Demonstraverunt congue nisl soluta tincidunt seacula. Soluta saepius demonstraverunt praesent claritatem mutationem. Modo te ullamcorper vel augue veniam. Nunc investigationes dolor iriure typi in.</p>
      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" summary="" border="0">
         <tbody>
            <thead>
               <tr>
                  <th>Heading 1</th>
                  <th>Heading 2</th>
                  <th>Heading 3</th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <tr>
               <td>sample</td>
               <td>sample</td>
               <td>sample</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>sample</td>
               <td>sample</td>
               <td>sample</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>sample</td>
               <td>sample</td>
               <td>sample</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>sample</td>
               <td>sample</td>
               <td>sample</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </html>
</customField>
```

**Do note:**

The "overriden identity rule" design pattern is used. This is the most fundamental and powerful XSLT design pattern.

**UPDATE**:

As noticed by Flynn1179, the OP's definition of the problem (above) is inconsistent with the output he provides as wanted result. In this output not only is the first `tr` inside of the `tbody` converted to `thead/tr` (and its `td` children to `th`), but the `thead` is moved outside of the `tbody`.

In case this is really what the OP wants, here is modified solution also for this case:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="tbody/tr[1]">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <xsl:apply-templates 
        select="following-sibling::tr"/>
  </tbody>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="tbody/tr[1]/td">
  <th>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </th>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="tbody">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="tr[1]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the same XML document, the result is**:

```
<customField name="mainContent" type="Html">
   <html>
      <h1>Page Heading</h1>
      <p>Gusto te minim tempor elit quam. Dolore vel accumsan parum option me. Demonstraverunt congue nisl soluta tincidunt seacula. Soluta saepius demonstraverunt praesent claritatem mutationem. Modo te ullamcorper vel augue veniam. Nunc investigationes dolor iriure typi in.</p>
      <p>Gusto te minim tempor elit quam. Dolore vel accumsan parum option me. Demonstraverunt congue nisl soluta tincidunt seacula. Soluta saepius demonstraverunt praesent claritatem mutationem. Modo te ullamcorper vel augue veniam. Nunc investigationes dolor iriure typi in.</p>
      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" summary="" border="0">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>Heading 1</th>
               <th>Heading 2</th>
               <th>Heading 3</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td>sample</td>
               <td>sample</td>
               <td>sample</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>sample</td>
               <td>sample</td>
               <td>sample</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>sample</td>
               <td>sample</td>
               <td>sample</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>sample</td>
               <td>sample</td>
               <td>sample</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </html>
</customField>
```

Comment: @Alejandro and @Flack: Thank you. Yes, this solution is completely "push" style, while the other solution is pull style ... In another topic, I think you'd be interested to read my latest blog post: "The Binary Search Tree Data Structure–having fun with XPath 3.0" at: http://dnovatchev.wordpress.com/2011/02/08/the-binary-search-tree-data-structurehaving-fun-with-xpath-3-0/

Comment: @Flynn1179: I am producing literally what the OP wants: "have some html content inside my XML. Previously I could just use `<xsl:copy-of select="customFields/customField[@name='mainContent']/html"/>` to pull the content into the correct area. A new requirement is to convert the first `<tr>` inside each table's `<tbody>` into a set of `thead/tr/th`."

Comment: I see what you mean, but I'd say it's ambiguous in that it's not clear from the description where the `thead` element should go. I looked at the desired output when I devised a solution, and noted that a `thead` tag inside a `tbody` tag would not be valid html. Interesting to note though, that your revised solution is no more 'push' style than mine. I wonder if there is a way of doing it purely in 'push' style.

Comment: My sample output is exactly as I wanted it, thanks for you second attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="tbody">
   <xsl:element name="thead">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="tr[1]" />
   </xsl:element>
   <xsl:element name="tbody">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="tr[position()!=1]" />
   </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="tr[1]/td">
   <xsl:element name="th">
     <xsl:apply-templates />
   </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It simply replaces your existing `tbody` element with a `thead` containing the first row, and a `tbody` containing all but the first, and then replaces all `td` elements in the first `tr` with `th` instead.

Comment: Thanks Flynn1179 for picking up on how I asked for the output.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="tbody">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="header"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="tr[1]"/>
    <xsl:template match="tr" mode="header"/>
    <xsl:template match="tr[1]" mode="header">
        <thead>
            <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
        </thead>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="tr[1]/td">
        <th>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </th>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<customField name="mainContent" type="Html">
    <html>
        <h1>Page Heading</h1>
        <p>Gusto te minim tempor elit quam. Dolore vel accumsan parum option me. Demonstraverunt congue nisl soluta tincidunt seacula. Soluta saepius demonstraverunt praesent claritatem mutationem. Modo te ullamcorper vel augue veniam. Nunc investigationes dolor iriure typi in.</p>
        <p>Gusto te minim tempor elit quam. Dolore vel accumsan parum option me. Demonstraverunt congue nisl soluta tincidunt seacula. Soluta saepius demonstraverunt praesent claritatem mutationem. Modo te ullamcorper vel augue veniam. Nunc investigationes dolor iriure typi in.</p>
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" summary="" border="0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Heading 1</th>
                    <th>Heading 2</th>
                    <th>Heading 3</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>sample</td>
                    <td>sample</td>
                    <td>sample</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>sample</td>
                    <td>sample</td>
                    <td>sample</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>sample</td>
                    <td>sample</td>
                    <td>sample</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>sample</td>
                    <td>sample</td>
                    <td>sample</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </html>
</customField>
```